# jQuery show - hide "read more" when is nessesary

Tags: javascript, jquery, sed

How can I show and hide button `read more` with jQuery. I don't know how to select full text length and check need to have "read more" button or not. I have limit for example of 1000 symbols and after that show me the button `read more`

For example I have a post and :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat... (read more) when click and I can see full text
```

But if I have less than for example 1000 symbols I want to say I do not need "read more" the text length in this limit and is not nessesary and "read more" button. need to be hidden .
Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried out some possible solution? If not, try some sample and come back with problem and tried code. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html:

```
<div class="more"> a lot of text </div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
var showChar = 130;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function() {
     var content = $(this).html();             
     if(content.length > showChar) {             
        var c = content.substr(0, showChar-1);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);             
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';             
        $(this).html(html);
     }             
});             
$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
 });
});
```

**BUT**: i couldnot finish the code, there is small bug in js, please work on this further. i need to study for my exam now.. sorry

this is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CbLbu/

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing this code as well:

```
 (function ($) {
  var _text = [],

  getText = function () {
    var div = $(this), text = div.text(), textLength = text.length, full, short;
    if (textLength > 100) {
        full = text;
        short = text.substr(0, 100);
        div.html(short + '... <span class="read-link read-more">read more</span>');
    } else full = text;
    _text.push({ full: full, short: short});
  };

  $('div').each(getText);

  $('div').on('click', '.read-link', function (index) {
    var span = $(this), div = span.parent();
    if (span.hasClass('read-more')) div.html(_text[div.index()].full + '... <span class="read-link read-less">read less</span>');
    else div.html(_text[div.index()].short + '... <span class="read-link read-more">read more</span>');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

[Here is example](http://jsbin.com/faken/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

if you have more card with text:

```
var _text = [],
        getText = function () {
            var div = $(this), text = div.text(), textLength = text.length, full, short;
            if (textLength > 172) {
                full = text;
                short = text.substr(0, 172);
                div.html(short + '... <span class="read-link read-more" ' +
                    'style ="color:#1976D2">(more)</span>');
            } else full = text;
            _text.push({full: full, short: short});
        };

    $('.more').each(getText).on('click', '.read-link', function (index) {
        var span = $(this), div = span.parent();
        var index = $(this).closest('.questions-list__card').index();
        if (span.hasClass('read-more')) div.html(_text[index].full + '... <span class="read-link read-less" style ="color:#1976D2">read less</span>');
        else div.html(_text[index].short + '... <span class="read-link read-more" ' +
            'style ="color:#1976D2">(more)</span>');
    });
});
```